# Will Carla ever forgive me?

Tags: fallout-4

I tried to rob trashcan carla in Sanctuary but failed. Now she refuses to sell to me and won't leave.

That happened several in-game days ago, will she ever get over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, according to the [Fallout wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Trashcan_Carla) she will never deal with you again.  But if you hadn't robbed her, and had instead given her a sarcastic response, she would have given you a discount.  *burn*